# Form submission delay using setTimer

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm simply trying to delay the form submission and provide the user some sense that an action is taking place, rather than just instant form submission. The jsfiddle linked below shows exactly what I'm trying to do (less the action taking place in the client I want to provide a message for).

In a nutshell, I thought to use setTimeout as a method to delay the form submission by N seconds, e.g.

```
// display message indicating we're doing something
$("#container").html("<p>Processing...</p>");

setTimeout(function () {
    // display message indicating we're ready to submit the form
    $("#container").html("<p>Submitting...</p>");
    // trigger form submit action
    form.submit();
    return true; // needed?
}, 2000);
```

As you can see here, I'm wrapping the "submitting..." message and the actual form submit trigger inside the setTimeout. This is all within a larger `$("#theForm").submit()` wrapper.

This either fails outright (hangs) or performs some sort of pseudo "partial submission" where the form goes through but yet the POST fails.

I'm not married to this idea... if there is another method of delaying form submit for a couple of seconds for the benefit of the user experience, I would like to know.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4tqy/

Browsers tested: Chrome, IE 8, FF 12 under Windows...this is all I have access to ATM.

Comment: It seems to work fine in FF12. EDIT: And Chrome Latest. There's a POST error, but that's coming from jsfiddle, I believe.

Comment: I assume the submit means you wish to navigate away from the page upon submission? Your canned html in the jsfiddle had no action in it, so it'll always hang.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind; you're clearing the `<div id="formContainer">` elements (including the `form`) when you set the messages. There's no form to submit at that point.

Comment: That's what the problem is! Right!

Comment: @Jared Farrish, @bdl - Correct, he needs to use `$('#container').append()` and instead of using the `<p>` tag, he should use a `<div>` tag that has a `position:absolute`. Of course for this to work you're going to need `position:relative` to the parent element so that it `works from the constraints of that element's margins.` **Also** You do not need to return true; for this statement to work.

Comment: @bdl, check your fiddle, i've updated it as Jared said. It works.

Comment: Why do you want to intentionally delay form submission?  There are piles of research that say you should *eliminate* all possible delay.  Instant form submission **is a good thing**.

Comment: I agree with @josh3736, you should be handling any delay that occurs, not inducing an artificial one.

Comment: @all> Thanks for your comments. I guess I should be handling the feedback on the server side, but I wanted to provide some feedback while the client processes their form in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the *why are you inducing a delay instead of eliminating any that occur...*

Using:

```
<div id="formMessage"></div>
<div id="formContainer">
```

And:

```
#formMessage {
    display: none;
}
```

And adding/editing:

```
$("#formContainer").hide();
$("#formMessage").html("Processing...").show();

....

$("#formMessage").html("Submitting....");
```

It works, as in this (admittedly roundabout) demonstration, you're not removing the `form` from the `#formContainer` element before you then try to submit it.

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/t4tqy/1/

Now, there's some improvements I might suggest, like using caching instead of multiple calls to the same element selector, etc. Plus, you can also create the `#formMessage` element only when you need it, instead of having unnecessary markup in your source.

```
$(function () {
    var $email = $("#emailAddr"),
        $form = $("#emailForm"),
        $container = $('#formContainer'),
        $message = $('<div id="formMessage">');

    $email.val('bogus.user@email.cc');

    $form.submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var form = this,
            ea = $email.val(),
            allowSubmit = false;

        // cheap email validation
        if (ea.length !== 0 && ea.indexOf("@") !== -1) {
            allowSubmit = true;
        }

        if (allowSubmit === true) {
            // indicate action of some sort
            $container.hide().before($message);
            $message.html("Processing...").show();

            setTimeout(function () {
                // indicate we're submitting form
                $message.html("Submitting...");
                // engage
                form.submit();
                return true;
            }, 2000);

        } else {
            alert("form not ok, not allowing submission...");
        }  
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/t4tqy/3/

Comment: isn't that what I did in the fiddle?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, that was obviously it! Will consider your other comments.